# Stopping Java timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

```
new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timeout--;
        if(timeout>=1){
            status1.setText("Time out: " + timeout);
        }else{
            patient1.setText("Patient: ");
            status1.setText("Status: Available");
            doctor.get(0).setStatus(true);
            countDoc++;
            setDoc.setText(avDoc + countDoc);
            timeout = 24;
        }
    }
}).start();
```

How to stop this piece of timer at the end of the else statement? I really scratched my head for this and searched almost everywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to stop the Timer from within its ActionListener, then  you can get the reference to the Timer object from the ActionEvent's `getSource()` method, and then stop it by calling `stop()` on the reference:

```
((timer) e.getSource()).stop();
```

or to break it down:

```
// assuming an ActionEvent variable named e
Timer timer = (Timer) e.getSource();
timer.stop();
```

and in context:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    timeout--;
    if(timeout>=1){
        status1.setText("Time out: " + timeout);
    }else{
        patient1.setText("Patient: ");
        status1.setText("Status: Available");
        doctor.get(0).setStatus(true);
        countDoc++;
        setDoc.setText(avDoc + countDoc);
        timeout = 24;

        ((timer) e.getSource()).stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it working now but another question.
 Timer timer = (Timer) e.getSource(); What does the Timer in bracket does?

Comment: @user3083413: I'm glad that you've got it working. What do you mean by "bracket"? Do you mean the `(Timer)` statement? That's a cast which is required since `getSource()` is declared to return Object.

Comment: Understood fully now. Thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

define the timer first as in:

```
Timer tim = new Timer(......)

tim.start();
tim.stop();
```

this will allow you yo stop the timer anywhere (providing you make it global)

you can also change it's attributes easily if you tie it to a var rather than creating an object like that..